# Vue.js single file component fails to import, "undefined has no properties"

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-i18n, vue-props, vue-sfc

I have a "Settings.vue" component:

```js
import MyDropdown from "./MyDropdown.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    MyDropdown,
  },
}
```

and a "MyDropdown.vue" component:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        value: {
            type: String,
        },
        label: {
            type: String,
            default: this.$t("label"),
        },
    },
};
```

When building, I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function MyDropdown() {
      return __webpack_require__.e(/*! import() */ 21).then(__webpack_require__.bind(null, /*! @/components/control/MyDropdown.vue */ "./src/components/control/MyDropdown.vue"));
    }
Reason: TypeError: undefined has no properties vue.runtime.esm.js:619
```

What could be causing the TypeError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MyDropdown.vue component, the default value for the label prop should be a factory function, rather than a value.

> [Object or array defaults must be returned from a factory function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation),

Even though the default in this case will resolve to a string, since it's using the `this.$t` function, it looks like using the factory is the right approach.

```js
default: this.$t("label"),
```

should be

```js
default: () => this.$t("label"),
```